# Nginx root dir is bad

Tags: nginx

I have a problem,

I have changed the directory of a subdomain in nginx,

Before pointed to:

```
/srv/www/musica
```

And now it aims at:

```
/srv/www/sonerezh
```

I have configured both:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/musica.conf
```

as:

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/musica.conf
```

To point to:

```
/srv/www/sonerezh
```

And I've restarted the services of php and nginx, but the nginx log tells me to keep looking on the path:

> 2017/05/24 08:54:26 [error] 1580 # 1580: * 9974
>
> /srv/www/musica/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory) ...

I do not understand why this is happening and the new directory path is not updated.

Comment: Either that file doesn't exist, or the user that the Nginx daemon is running as doesn't have access. Check your nginx.conf for the user it runs as, then compare that with the file permissions.

Comment: Update the permissions and now gives me this error:

2017/05/24 11:20:15 [error] 1580 # 1580: * 10109 "/srv/www/musica/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied),

But strangely the route still changes.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test the configuration and identify what files `nginx` is actually reading.

Comment: @RichardSmith The configuration is correct and you are using the musica.conf file

Comment: Is `/srv/www/musica` mentioned anywhere in the configuration?

Comment: No, nowhere, I've already reviewed it

Comment: Do you have multiple nginx versions on your server? Are you sure you restarted the correct one? Are you sure there is a symlink from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` to `sites-available` for the site?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes, yes and yes

Comment: And are you sure that the version you restarted uses `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` configuration and not something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restarting the server was solved